# Javascript Using Math.random to generate random rgba values in for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, rgba

I'm very new at this and apologise if it's a silly question. This is just a simple for loop to draw n amount of circles and I want to randomly generate rgba values but it takes the last strokeStyle used instead, what am I doing wrong?

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
var x = Math.random() * window.innerWidth;
var y = Math.random() * window.innerHeight;
var colour = Math.random() * 255;

c.beginPath();
c.arc(x, y, 30, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
c.strokeStyle = 'rgba(colour, colour, colour, Math.random())';
c.stroke(); }
```

Thank you so much!!

Comment: Did you mean to *concatenate*? Right now you just have a string which is literally `rgba(colour, colour, colour, Math.random())`

Comment: @CertainPerformance Yeah I didn't realise that variables wouldn't work. However, if you just use numbers you can write it within quotes, like 'rgba(120, 2, 134, 0.4)', how come that doesn't act as just a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done by formatting a color string as follows:

```
"rgba(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + "," + a + ")";
```

where `r`, `g`, `b` are integers in the range of 0 to 255, and `a` is a floating point in the range of 0.0 to 1.0;

For a complete example see the following code snippet:

```js
var c = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

  const x = Math.random() * c.canvas.width;
  const y = Math.random() * c.canvas.height;

  // Red, green, blue should be integers in the range of 0 - 255
  const r = parseInt(Math.random() * 255);
  const g = parseInt(Math.random() * 255);
  const b = parseInt(Math.random() * 255);
  
  // Alpha is a floating point in range of 0.0 - 1.0
  const a = Math.random();

  c.beginPath();
  c.arc(x, y, 30, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  c.strokeStyle = "rgba(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + "," + a + ")";
  c.stroke();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Alternatively, if your target browser supports "template literals" then the same color string can be formatted in a more concise way via the following:

```
const r = parseInt(Math.random() * 255);
const g = parseInt(Math.random() * 255);
const b = parseInt(Math.random() * 255);
const a = Math.random();

// Format color string via template literal using back ticks ` and ${} 
// to render scope variables to the string result
c.strokeStyle = `rgba(${r}, ${g}, ${b}, ${a})`;
```

Answer (score 1):

`'rgba(colour, colour, colour, Math.random())'` is a literal string, which makes it an invalid CSS (since CSS won't recognise either `colour` or `Math.random()`), which will be discarded.

You might want a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) instead (notice the different quote):

```
c.strokeStyle = `rgba(${colour}, ${colour}, ${colour}, ${Math.random()})`
```

Also, note that this will not give you quite a random colour; it will give you a random *grey* colour, as you linked the R, G and B component to be the same `colour`. If you want the three components to be able to differ, you need to generate a new random number for each component.